# Unable to load DLL 'Dll1.dll': This operation is only valid in the context of an app container. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007109A)

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, .net, dll

I have an ASP.net application that is trying to invoke methods from a c++ dll (called Dll1.dll) using pInvoke.

This is the Dll1.cpp:

```
Tester::Tester() {

}

void Tester::hello() {
    int i = 0;
}

DLL_API void  Tester_hello(Tester* pObj) { pObj->hello(); }

DLL_API Tester* Tester_Create() { return new Tester(); }

DLL_API void Tester_Delete(Tester* pObj) { delete pObj; }
```

This is the DLL.h:

```
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)

class DLL_API Tester {
public:
    Tester();
    void hello();
};
```

And this is where I am trying to load the dll in my asp.net application. Note I am calling it from the WebApiConfig just to try this and make sure it works:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    [DllImport("Dll1.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr Tester_Create();

    [DllImport("Dll1.dll")]
    static extern void Tester_hello(IntPtr pObj);

    [DllImport("Dll1.dll")]
    static extern void Tester_Delete(IntPtr pObj);


    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        IntPtr h = Tester_Create(); <- Exception thrown here
        Tester_hello(h);
        Tester_Delete(h);
    }
}
```

However, when I run the following application, I get this error:

**[DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Dll1.dll': This operation is only valid in the context of an app container. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007109A)]**

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Did you solve it? cause I'm in this situation

Comment: I did solve it. Its been a while but I think the problem was that I was building my Dll1.dll as a winrt dll which ASP.NET cannot load unless its one of the winrt dlls that come as part of windows (basically it cant sideload winrt dlls that aren't made by Microsoft). In order to get my dll to load, I had to recompile it as a native c++ dll.